# How to get the same position on two ArrayListif I have removed a value from the first ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("king", "king", "queen", "jack", "queen"));

ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "one", "one", "two", "one"));
```

In the List named `firstList` I'll remove the duplicate using `Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>(firstList);` and the output will be `"king", "queen", "jack"`

What I want to do is get the position on the `secondList` equal to the position on the `firstList`.

The current output is `(king & one), (queen, one), (jack, one)`

What I want the output to be is `(king, one), (queen, one), (jack, two)`

If any of you could help me, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Why don't you remove the duplicates from the second List too?

Comment: why do you even need the second list? it seems like all you need is to find the index of the element in the first list/hashSet and add 1

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't use two independent data structures (`List`s) for this but instead a `Map<String, String>`. Would that be an option?

Comment: oops my bad wrong values from `secondList` I edited my post @Eran thats why I can't remove the duplicate

Comment: I can't see the relationship between the numbers in the second list and the de-depulicated values in the first. Why do "King" and "Queen" map to "one" but "Jack" to two??

Comment: Edited again lol my bad

Comment: @PPartisan I absolutely  agree with you. I can also not see any relationship why jack is two

Comment: I edited my post please check hehehehehehe

Comment: How are you sure that all `"king"` in first list is always in front of `"one"` in the second ? Wich `"one"` should be kept and which should be ignored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your two input lists are always the same length you can do something simple like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> firstList  = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("king", "king", "queen", "jack", "queen"));
    List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "one", "one", "two", "one"));

    List<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< firstList.size(); i++){
        String temp = firstList.get(i);
        if(!cards.contains(temp)){
            cards.add(temp); 
            positions.add(secondList.get(i)); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cards);
    System.out.println(positions);
}
```

Comment: So i will not use the `HashSet` to remove the duplicate values?

Comment: Yes, you keep your input lists `firstList & secondList`  unchanged.  By iterating over your firstList and adding only unique values to the cards list you produce a copy of firstlist without duplicates. And in the positions list you add the elements from secondList which have the same index as the unique values in firstlist.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map`. In Java 8, it would be (in the form of a passing unit test):

```
    final List<String> one = asList("king", "king", "queen", "jack", "queen");
    final List<String> two = asList("one", "one", "one", "two", "one");

    //Guards against IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions
    final int size = Math.min(one.size(), two.size()); 
    //LinkedHashMap to preserve key ordering
    final Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        map.putIfAbsent(one.get(i), two.get(i));
    }

    final String actual = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> String.format("[%s,%s]", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    final String expected = "[king,one],[queen,one],[jack,two]";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

For Java 7, you need to check the `Map` doesn't already contain the key before you add it. `putIfAbsent()` does this for you otherwise.

You can stream the `Map` values and keys afterwards if you want to do different things with them:

```
    final String keys = String.join(",", map.keySet());
    assertEquals("king,queen,jack", keys);

    final String values = String.join(",", map.values());
    assertEquals("one,one,two", values);
```

Comment: I think the OP need two list index by index, I think you've gone so far.

Comment: What if i dont want to concatenate it I want to set it to two different  `textview` ?

Comment: Then stream the `values()` and `keySet()` independently (I'll update my answer)

Comment: Thank you i'll wait

Comment: `String.join` requires API level 26 sad. Can't use this code

Comment: You can just concat your own `String` in a `for` loop with a `StringBuilder` the old-fashioned way. You don't need to use these Java 8 techniques, they're just examples.